# Can gedit highlight element of svg stucture?

Tags: xml, gedit, syntax-highlighting, svg

Gedit can show matching parenthesis. Can it do the same with tags of an SVG file ?
For example when I mark `<text>` I need to find closing `</text>` tag.

Comment: [Follow this Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20879/gedit-plugin-for-html-tag-match)

Comment: Now I use XML Copy Editor (http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net ). It can hide and show tags and attributes